# put reviews in google reviews using react and google API

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-reviews

I want to put review in google from my database, is there any google API provides this feature ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems that you can't write a review with Google API.
You can just get reviews and reply to reviews with Google Business API.

I don't think it will ever be possible to allow a third party to post Google reviews coming from a database. The best thing to do in my opinion would be to ask the authors of your reviews to write them directly on Google.

Here, some people ask for features to the support:
[support.google.com Post Review Programmatically](https://support.google.com/business/thread/1880041/post-review-programmatically?hl=en)

However, some companies that have a partnership with Google offer the possibility of writing a Google review directly on your website by your users.

Here is an example : [Birdeye.com Get New Review](https://support.birdeye.com/review-marketing/1205086-how-can-i-get-new-reviews-on-google-using-direct-google-reviews)